# Unable to install packages in R

Tags: r, linux

I accidentally removed the files in the `/tmp` folder using Linux CentOs7.
After that I cannot install any packages in R studio.
please help!

> Warning in install.packages :   cannot open compressed file
>   '/tmp/Rtmpf0wKDi/repos_https%3A%2F%2Fcran.rstudio.com%2Fsrc%2Fcontrib.rds',
>   probable reason 'No such file or directory' Warning in
>   install.packages :   cannot open compressed file
>   '/tmp/Rtmpf0wKDi/file5b9531125101', probable reason 'No such file or
>   directory' Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for 
>   repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:   cannot open the
>   connection Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Comment: Not exactly sure when R create a new subfolder in `/tmp`, but what I would try is restart the R session or the system. If that doesn't work, there may be permission issues?

Comment: After restart R, I can install packages in R stuido. "sudo service shiny-server restart", THANK YOU Roman Luštrik :)

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer for future reference.